# Haskell lazy evaluation in parallelism

Tags: haskell, parallel-processing, lazy-evaluation

If value `x` is in a list where `x` is some function
and `parList` is called on that list (e.g `[l,x,l,x]`)
does `x` get calculated once or twice?

From my understanding of Haskell's lazy evaluation, once `x` has been evaluated it doesn't need to be evaluated again as it would return the same value. But would this apply in a multi-threaded environment?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Whenever you create a *spark* for a computation
(which is what `parList` does) there is always a possibility
that the work for that computation will be performed twice.
In practice this happens rarely. Basically there is a race condition
between the threads processing the sparks and the main thread.

Haskell implements laziness by initially setting the value of a variable
to a *thunk* - essentially a pointer to code to compute the value.
When the value of the variable is demanded, Haskell runs the code pointed
to by the thunk and replaces the thunk with the returned value.
If the variable is used later, Haskell just uses the stored value.

When you evaluate a variable in parallel a *spark* is created pointing to
the variable. When the spark is processed by a background thread it
just demands the value that the spark points to. If the spark points
to a thunk, the thunk is run and updated with the returned value.
If the spark points to an already evaluated value, nothing happens
and we say that the spark *fizzles*.

Thus, if you evaluate a list like `[x,x,x,x,x,x]` in parallel, one spark
will be created for each element of the list, and it is possible that
two or more of those sparks will execute at the same time. It is also
possible that the main thread will be evaluating `x` at the same time.
In that case the work to compute `x` will be duplicated.
However, once the thunk for `x` has been updated, no spark or main thread
evaluations of `x` starting after that will recompute `x`.

Comment: Cheers, I've got another follow up question. Consider we have 2 reasonably long durations of spark. Imagine the first spark accesses and computes `x` but doesn’t not return. Meanwhile in a parallel but subsequent to that calculation, the second spark access `x`. Does that spark obtains the value of `x` from the calculation of first spark or does it calculate `x` itself?

Comment: If a computation needs the value of `x` and `x` is currently a thunk, it will perform the work to compute `x`, update `x` with the computed value (so `x` is no longer a thunk) and continue on.

Comment: Yes, thanks for that, but my question is about the interaction of lazy evaluation and sparks. I am trying to understand if an evaluated thunk from one spark becomes available to another spark that was started before the thunk was evaluated. Say I have two sparks S1 and S2 presently running in parallel, and both of which were passed a thunk to x initially at time t0. At time t1, some time after S1 and S2 have started, S1 accesses x, thus evaluating the thunk. Let us presume the thunk evaluation completes at time t2. At time t3, (where t3 > t2), spark S2 accesses x.

Comment: For clarity, let us presume that S1 terminates at t4 where t4 > t3. My question is whether S2 obtains the value of x, or executes the thunk to obtain the value of x?

If it gains access to the value and does not evaluate the thunk, this suggests to me a classic threading model whereby values of shared variables are visible concurrently to all threads. If not, this suggests more of a fork style model, whereby each spark is given an initialised state that is isolated for the duration of its execution. Thanks.

Comment: Once a thread (including sparks) converts a thunk to a value it is visible to all  other threads/sparks.